# Row backbround gets cut off

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview

i have a table.. where i try to show this image in every row.

[image: The correct image how it should show..]

But when i do

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BlueLong.png"]];
```

the outcome is this..

[image]

The first row is correct.. but after that its like the upper side of the image gets cutted..?
how can i fix this?

Ty already!

Comment: i would use a stretchable uiimage: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:

Comment: hmm , i cant seem to get it to work.. can you show me some examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Stretchableimage] stretch.png - it is your image reduced to the shadow and shape

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"stretch.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:21.0 topCapHeight:15.0]];
```

21 and 15 is the center of the Image with the size 42x31 Pixels

EDIT: This should work

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"stretch.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:21 topCapHeight:15]];
```

Comment: its not a trick ;) what is the result? Have you used MY image?

Comment: there is no result because nothing happens :D, im using this cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"BlueLong.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:550 topCapHeight:79]]; image size is 1100, 158

Comment: the image is to big, it can't scale smaller than it is only bigger, so you need to cut all things out you dont need, like you see in my image, only the shadow and shape is left.
So use my picture for a try

Comment: if i try to use ur image, the image wont stretch but instead it duplicates them like this. http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/27/schermafbeelding2011082u.png/  , maybe im forgetting to change a property?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried implementing the UITableViewDelegate method `(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` To tell the row how tall it should be?

Comment: Yes, i did but that has nothing to do with it because as you can see the third and last row's height are different from the rest.